# awaitAll Ordering with Kotlin coroutine

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to look more into the awaitAll of coroutines as I have a few DB calls that I would like to all launch and wait until theyre all done to aggregate the result.

However, the tricky part I am finding with the current `awaitAll` implementation is that it just returns a list. I wonder how do I find the original requested call if I wanted to act differently on each result?

My current implementation (without knowing who is the source of deferred task)

```
val dbClient = ArrayList<String>
val dbCallTasks = ArrayList<Deferred<Map<String, Set<String>>?>>()
withContext(IO) {
    for (client in dbClients){
        dbClient.add(client.getName())
        val deferredTask = async {
            withTimeoutOrNull(1000L) {
                client.getItems(instanceList)
            }
        }
        doCallTasks.add(deferredTask)
    }
    dbCallTasks.awaitAll()
}
```

But this doesnt really tell me who the results are from which client in dbClients... I dont see much implementation in the awaitAll except for calling it against a
`kotlin.collections.Collection<kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred<T>>.awaitAll()`

There is this implementation

`awaitAll(vararg deferreds: kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred<T>): kotlin.collections.List<T>`
where this would be I guess aggregating a list of Deferred into a List, does the List output guarantee ordering? Theoretically I would assume it does but that also means if I were to loop through the entries for my Map<String, Set<>> it should also be the same ordering on the second time around to find the result.

EDIT:
So I decided to use 2 lists, if `awaitAll()` is ordered. That means my insertion into the list, where each index `i` should correspond from the name of the client to the deferred job submitted.
I can't tell if I am writing the UT incorrectly, but cant seem to repro this properly which makes me think it isnt guaranteed ordering.

```
coEvery { dbClient.getName() } returns "A" andThen "B" andThen "C"
coEvery { dbClient.getItems(any()) } returns aHashMap andThen bHashMap andThen cHashMap
```

Each time I run this iteration, my results comes out differently for the result of the `awaitAll()`

```
[A, B, C]
[{}, {C=[i-DontCare]}, {}]
```

```
[A, B, C]
[{C=[i-DontCare]}, {}, {}]
```

And sometimes it is in the correct spot. Which makes me think it is more randomized.

```
[A, B, C]
[{}, {}, {C=[i-DontCare]}]
```

Or maybe there is more complex logic to testing async code.

Comment: Yes, `awaitAll()` returns items in the same order as deferred.

Comment: Hmm, so I guess my dilemma in this case is not using a hash map and have two list to track in an ordered list manner since HashMap does not guarantee consistent iteration

Comment: Cant tell if united test is not properly working  or awaitAll doesnt guarantee ordering... I created two list which is the client name and deferred job. In the same order hence in theory, their indexes corresponds to each other. But I cant seem to get a correct repro that the ordering are consistent in UT

`clientName=[A, B, C] response=[{}, {}, {A=[i-DontCare]}]`

Comment: I believe the problem is with your tests. You don't know what will be the order of `getItems()` calls. For example, first call to `getItems()` is for client `B` and then you mock `aHashMap` as a result.

Comment: Is there a way to enforce this ordering in UT to get more consistent result to reflect behavior that will happen in production?

Comment: I cant tell though why I wont know the order of `getItems()` when I have it in the UT. Because that works for other test cases, only this particular section where I am using an async task

Comment: Well, I don't understand your case fully, but by looking into code it seems you have 3 so called "db clients", each of them has its own data. But by looking into your mocks it looks like you create only a single db client that tries to act as 3 separate objects. And it fails doing this. Why won't you create 3 separate objects when testing?

Comment: I guess I could, let me try it. Because all the clients are under the same base class, so I made it easier on myself I suppose. Let me see if that will make any difference

Comment: Looks like you were right, it seems like if I want to mock 3x async object calls, I need to have 3 different mocks... Wonder why :p

Comment: The problem is more generic, you only observed it with async calls. Do something like below and you will see similar problems: `val (clientA, clientB, clientC) = dbClients; clientC.getItems() // you get items of A`. We can't reliably represent 3 different objects by a single one. The only reason why it worked so far is because you crafted your tests precisely to succeed, not to fail ;-)